# With JavaScript Flow, how to limit allowed values to type's keys?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

What should be put in place of `???` so that the following would work:

```
type Product = {
    id: number,
    name: string;
}

const foo: ??? = 'id' // works
const bar: ??? = 'name' // works
const baz: ??? = 'someField' // FAIL!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`$Keys` utility type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-keys) that will extract all keys from a type and produce a union of them.

```
type Product = {
    id: number,
    name: string;
}

const foo: $Keys<Product> = 'id' // works
const bar: $Keys<Product> = 'name' // works
const baz: $Keys<Product> = 'someField' // FAIL!
```

[See a live example](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgTgewCYFcDGwoF4oG8BQURUAlkgFxQB2KAtgEYRwA0hxVAhrRJQM7BwSVAOYBufAF98+NAir8oAMwQJKAEgDSEELwA88ZOmAA+bFADkZc1AD0NqAHcEcANa8ZchfQ5x1WnfqIqBimOOac3NZ2js5uHvKY3gBeftp6BsEmZua8CNwAYiQQADZIUfb5AIIAkgAyAIRAA)

In effect `$Keys<Product>` is the same as `"id" | "name"` but it's dynamically calculated based on the properties present in `Product`. You can also extract the type if you want to re-use it a lot:

```
type ValidKey = $Keys<Product>

const foo: ValidKey = "id"
```